# Why won't use of static equals compile?

Tags: java

If I have a class `Equals` in a file

```
package com;

public class Equals implements Clause {
    public Equals(String field, Object value) {

    }

    public static Equals equals(String field, Object value) {
        return new Equals(field, value);
    }
}
```

and another file that imports the method and uses it.

```
package com;
import static com.Equals.equals;

public class A {
    public void use() {
        equals("field", "value");
    }
}
```

why won't this compile.

```
C:\project\src\test\java\com\A.java:6: error: method equals in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
        equals("field", "value");
        ^
  required: Object
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Looks like it's trying to run `this.equals()` instead of `Equals.equals()`.

Comment: @azurefrog yes of course but why?

Comment: I think the answers on the linked question cover it pretty thoroughly.

Comment: It does! Thank you!